# meson-python: error: Could not find ninja version 1.8.2 or newer while installing pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas

I am deploying my Django app on shared hosting via name cheap. I am using cPanel shell terminal. I have some dependencies on requirements.txt file. I am installing it via terminal session but unable to install numpy or pandas it shows the following error. So the problem here is I already have installed the ninja version 1.11.1 and required is 1.8.2 or newer so basically it is not detecting the ninja. I also have downgraded the ninja version and tried different combinations but nothing works. Any help will be appriciated.

```
((app:3.11)) [abc@server123 simply]$ pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.2.1.tar.gz (4.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      Collecting meson-python==0.13.1
        Using cached meson_python-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
      Collecting meson==1.2.1
        Using cached meson-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting Cython==3.0.5
        Using cached Cython-3.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting numpy<=2.0.0.dev0,>1.22.4
        Using cached numpy-1.26.4.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [2 lines of output]

            ('\x1b[31m',)meson-python: error: Could not find ninja version 1.8.2 or newer.
            [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
      ╰─> See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I am using

```
python version 3.11.5
asgiref==3.7.2
Django==5.0.3
PyMySQL==1.1.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
tzdata==2024.1
ninjas==1.11.1
pandas
```

I have tried to download it using GitHub by cloning the repository but still it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual environment using venv or virtualenv to isolate project dependencies and avoid conflicts with system-wide libraries:

```
python -m venv my_venv 

source my_venv/bin/activate  # Activate the virtual environment
```

**Install pandas within the virtual environment:**

> pip install pandas

**If running your Django app requires manage.py, activate the virtual environment before running it:**

> source my_venv/bin/activate

**After that :**

> python manage.py runserver